# Perl WWW::Mechanize and pages that redirect automatically after a countdown

Tags: perl, http, redirect, www-mechanize

I have a script that can log into a webpage when it finds a login/sign-in form on a webpage. Everything works perfectly, even if the page is a redirect as it finds the Location element in the http header and follows it and so on..

However, the issue I am having relates to websites that display a page first with a message saying "You will be automatically redirected in 5 seconds", (or something similar) and *then* redirects you to the page after the 5 second countdown.

What is happening:

1. Mechanize is GETting the URL.
2. It reaches the page that says "You will be automatically redirected in 5 seconds", but because this page has loaded properly and is just a normal page with a 200 status (rather than a redirect status as the redirect only occurs after 5 seconds), it thinks that there is no redirect on this page so it will look for a login form and try and login.

But obviously a login form doesn't exist because it is just the small page you see briefly before the redirect actually occurs.

Does Mechanize have the capacity to deal with instances such as this and if so how?

The only way I can see possible is by following the redirect link that is usually provided for users to click if the page doesn't automatically redirect itself.

Comment: These redirects are often done with JavaScript. You can use Mechanize::Firefox to execute JS on a page. Most reputable sites that use such redirects (e.g. download links for sourceforge projects) also have a “klick here if it doesn't work” link, which you could extract and follow.

Comment: Yes i just realised that as it says text/javascript in the http header. Yeah thats the only other way I could see it was possible  as well, by following the link it provides you if it dosnt automatically redirect.

Comment: The only issue with following the "click here if it dosnt work link" is that you would have to know that the page you are running the script against either has or has not got a javascript redirect feature on it, because if it dosn't there is no reliable/universal way across all websites of knowing that a particular link on a page is a "click here if it dosn't work" link (as there is nothing special that identifies it as such, other than possibly the text that is associated with the link and that will differ a lot from site to site).

Comment: From the WWW::Mechanize FAQ: [Which modules work like Mechanize and have JavaScript support?](http://p3rl.org/WWW::Mechanize::FAQ#Which-modules-work-like-Mechanize-and-have-JavaScript-support)